# Convert CSV file to AVRO in scala

Tags: scala, avro

I am new to scala. I am trying to convert a CSV file to avro format. I tried to google about this and unable to find anything. I have given my sample Input file used and AVSC format(again from google).

```
{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "User",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
     {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

sample file:

```
name_1,12,yellow
name_2,22,red
name_3,32,green
```

Also, how can I scale up this to a Control A separated file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is the usage of [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) from databricks.
It looks like this:

```
import com.databricks.spark.avro._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("data.csv")
df.write.avro("converted.avro")
```

Like alternative for test purposes only you can use [this script on python](https://gist.github.com/lordjc/9694632)